# simple JSP Page not loading

Tags: java, html, jsp

Getting an error for the following jsp code:

```
 <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
String user=request.getParameter("userid"); 
session.putValue("userid",user); 
String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
String fname=request.getParameter("fname"); 
String lname=request.getParameter("lname"); 
String email=request.getParameter("email"); 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
"root","123"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs; 
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users values ('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+fname+"',
'"+lname+"','"+email+"')"); 


%>
```

The error am getting is as follow:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /db/reg.jsp
String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
12: "root","123"); 
13: Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
14: ResultSet rs; 
15: int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users values ('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+fname+"',
16: '"+lname+"','"+email+"')"); 
17: 
18: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I do not know what is going wrong over here. I am new to jsp so please help me with a simple explanation. The port number, user name password and everything else it correct for jsp file. Is there something else I am overlooking. Please help me to rectify the error.

Comment: I don't think you've shown the right bit of your JSP. You've shown a bit that does a select, but your error refers to an insert.

Comment: sorry wrong code. check now i have edited it

Comment: ..and another thing. You say you are learning JSP, so I'd like to point out that there are many Bad Things in your example, such as doing DB work in the JSP, and SQL injection.

Comment: You have to put try and catch block also.. As Class.forName throws ClassNotFoundException.. and db connection also...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly , [don't use scriptlets in JSP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), you can have this logic in Servlet or some DAO class.

Next thing , the below line should be a single line :

```
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","123");
```

Even put this in a single line :

```
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users values ('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"')");
```

Better construct a query string with placeholders and use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and set each value . It will prevent all these String formatting issues as well as from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
String query = "insert into users values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(user);
.............
.............
int updateSuccessful = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: what is the problem in the query statement?

Comment: see i got this example from http://www.9lessons.info/2008/09/jsp-login-page-to-connect-mysql-atabase.html,

Comment: it seems to be working ok there. I just want to know why the existing code is not working

Comment: You saw the site? can you help me with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Suspecting on `String` formatting, try this:

```
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+
"test","root","123");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include the String literal with double quotes -> ". I cannot run the code, but your error is in your sql statement. The term 'insert into user values' is interpreted as a String.

Comment: it should be interpreted as a string, shouldn it?

Comment: Try the hint that The New Idiot has answered. Sorry i do not want to be offensive. It is just his nick. You can better use 'prepared statements' with placeholders and insert the values, later.